# What does 'on-premises' mean?

Tags: meaning, terminology, software

Here is the example sentence.

> Windows Azure Caching was developed from an **on-premises** Caching
>   solution that shipped with Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server.

What does 'on-premises' mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***[On-Premise](http://info.appdirect.com/channel/resources/glossary)***

> Traditional method of installing and customizing software on the customer’s own computers that reside inside their own data center.

***[On-premises software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-premises_software)***

> (often abbreviated as on-prem software, and also called “on-premises” software) is installed and run on computers on the premises (in the building) of the person or organisation using the software, rather than at a remote facility, such as at a server farm or cloud somewhere on the internet. On-premises software is sometimes referred to as “shrinkwrap” software, and off-premises software is commonly called “software as a service” or “computing in the cloud”.

Related: [On-premises/on-prem, off-premises applications, what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2617456)